# Why is Stack Overflow on its own chat network?

Tags: support, chat

I've been looking around trying to find an answer to this question, but I haven't actually found a resource that gives a good answer. It continues to surprise me that chat is as separated as it is.

I ask because I can see the possibility for a couple good arguments as to why this should be the case, but they aren't immediately obvious to me. Still, I have to acknowledge the possibility that this configuration was intentional, since it seems too weird to be unintentional.

Is there a good reason why Stack Overflow chat is still on its network? If not, what is the historical reason/how did this come about?

Comment: Are you asking why chat (regardless of platform) exists in the first place, why we aren't using a third-party chat system, or something else?

Comment: You are aware there are 3 production chatservers, right? chat.so, chat.se and chat.mse. Or what Adam says...

Comment: @AdamLear I'm wondering why there are separate servers; i.e., why moderation, privileges, etc. don't carry over between Stack Overflow chat and Stack Exchange chat (and, indirectly, if they can be unified).

Comment: @Emrakul Ahh, gotcha. Thanks.

Comment: Related: [Assimilate chat.MSE into chat.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233734/180276).

Comment: If chats and sites were *merged*, what would be the consequences? I know websites privileges but I don't see how they would apply on chatrooms.

Comment: I suspect it's just for historical reasons, no deep thought or planning behind it.

Comment: If merging chat.so with chat.se means I'll get mod privileges on chat.so then... please let's keep them separate.

Comment: @Yannis If that ever happened, it doesn't mean you'd have to use the privileges.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Originally the idea was for each Stack Exchange site to have its own associated chat site. There was chat.stackoverflow.com, chat.superuser.com, chat.askubuntu.com, chat.webapps.stackexchange.com (there was also chat.nothingtoinstall.com, but [that's a whole other story](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/domain-names-the-wrong-question/)).

But we soon realized that for most sites, the chat sites ended up being pretty sad and lonely places, with just one or two chat rooms each. And so in January 2011 we decided to create a single chat.stackexchange.com instead, with chat rooms for all the different sites. The only exception (other than then-MSO, now-MSE, which is always a special case) was the Stack Overflow chat, which had (and has) enough rooms and activity to warrant having its own site.

Rooms on chat.stackoverflow.com tend to be organized around tags (or related technology groupings), whereas for most other Stack Exchange sites the discussion concentrates in a single general chat rooms for the whole site (imagine such a room for Stack Overflow!).

Chat.SO and chat.SE have similar amounts of activity (on the order of 600k messages per month these days), so if chat.SE were to assimilate chat.SO, half of the mega chat site's activity would be from Stack Overflow, drowning everything else.

So, like so often when the question is "Why is X different about Stack Overflow?", the answer is "Because of volume."

Comment: "**other than then-MSO, now-MSE, which is always a special case**" Would you be able to elaborate? I'm not sure I understand why MSE has a separate chat server

Comment: Even though MSE and SO are on separate servers due to the size, why do the reputation requirements for privileges on the separate chat servers have to be site-specific?

Answer (score -1):

It's on its own network for historical reasons.

It's *still* on its own network because there is a cost to migrating everything to *chat.SE*, and so far the benefits have not been worth that cost.

Pretty normal software development stuff.

Comment: If we are widely guessing why don't you add scaling/performance or even staging? That is also pretty normal software development and deployment stuff.

Comment: I'm glad I made at least someone smile today ....