# Why can't I chat here as I have 51 reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, chat

I have 51 reputation on one of the Stack Exchange sites. Because of this, why can't I chat in rooms?

Comment: 51 reputation? On which site? [Here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/334507/manoj-agrawal) it seems you don't have any reputation at all.

Comment: Area 51. you can see it

Comment: You have 26 according to me

Comment: only right now as i got some upvotes in this post

Comment: @Lee not at time of writing.

Comment: right man @John

Answer (score 10):

We have three chat servers - one serves this site, so you need 20 reputation *here* in this site, in order to chat on http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com.

The second serves Stack Overflow - so you need 20 rep there to chat on https://chat.stackoverflow.com.

The last one serves the rest of the network, including Area51. You need 20 rep on any of the other sites in order to chat on https://chat.stackexchange.com.

Comment: **Why** do we have different chat servers?

Comment: @John - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270272/why-is-stack-overflow-on-its-own-chat-network

Comment: Makes sense, but why does stackexchange allow creating MSE or SO rooms associated with the chat.se server if one of those sites was the one selected when a room was created from chat.se?

Comment: @John I am having problems parsing that. What problem do you see here, exactly?

Comment: It is possible to create rooms that have MSE as their associated that are on the chat.se server, NOT on the chat.meta.se server, like [this](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60556/place-where-cats-eat) one. It has MSE as its associated site, yet it is on the chat.se server, not on the chat.meta.SE server.

Comment: And why is this a problem, @John?

Comment: It decreases the viewability of the rooms that are on the wrong server since those rooms are not listed on the per-site list of rooms, and room-owners who don't realize that their rooms are on the wrong server will not know why their rooms get less attention (the room I created was just a test to see if it would allow wrong-server rooms). **I think those thousands of wrong-server  rooms on SO associated with chat.SE should be migrated, so they will not be nearly invisible.**